# LFS 7.2: Hundreds of errors in glibc make check

Tags: linux, makefile, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am on [Section 6.9](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/glibc.html) of the LFS book. Everything before this section seemed fine.

When I ran `make check` I got a huge number of errors. A longer transcript of my `make check` run can be found [here on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6zeMkNhk).

```
Summary of test results:
    865 FAIL
   1308 PASS
    202 XFAIL
Makefile:321: recipe for target 'tests' failed
make[1]: *** [tests] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.21'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

I'm wondering, if looking at the transcript anyone can infer something obvious that I did incorrectly. I think I followed the book word for word, but I may have missed something along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that GLIBC `make check` expects some basic command to be present, but that command is missing from your `LFS` system.

I just checked my GLIBC build, and all the `conform` tests use `/usr/bin/perl`.

Look for errors in `conform/XPG4/locale.h/linknamespace.out`. The problem will likely be obvious.

> `/bin/sh: line 2: no: command not found`

So it's likely that `configure` looked for `perl`, didn't find it, and set `PERL` in `config.make` to `no`.

To fix this, you need to install `perl` before you can run `make check`.

Comment: I have this output: `113 FAIL - 2198 PASS - 88 XFAIL - 3 XPASS` - where can I check what is the problem? My `conform/XPG4/locale.h/linknamespace.out` file is empty. The other files have all OK inside.

Comment: @AI tests.sum and subdir-tests.sum